# Creating HTML form with Spring+Hibernate

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have 3 classes:

First class, is an entity, that stores String variable:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mods_langs_texts", catalog = "artfunpw")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class ModsLangsTexts implements java.io.Serializable {


    @Column(name = "Title", nullable = false, length = 300)
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
```

Second entity is for relations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mods_langs_texts_relations", catalog = "artfunpw")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class ModsLangsTextsRelations implements java.io.Serializable {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "textId", nullable = false)
    public ModsLangsTexts getModsLangsTexts() {
        return this.modLangsTexts;
    }
```

And the third entity is the main class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mods", catalog = "artfunpw")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class Mod implements java.io.Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "mod")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    public Set<ModsLangsTextsRelations> getModsLangsTextsRelationses() {
        return this.modsLangsTextsRelationses;
    }
```

I am trying to create HTML form with the code:

```
m.addAttribute("formClass", mod);
```

And HTML code:

```
<p th:text="${formClass.modsLangsTextsRelationses.toArray()[0].getModsLangsTexts().title}" />

                <form action="" th:object='${formClass}' method="POST">

                    <input type="hidden" th:field='*{id}' />

                    Title: <input type="text" th:field='${formClass.modsLangsTextsRelationses.toArray()[0].getModsLangsTexts().title}' />
                    <br />
```

But it fails with error:

```
2017-10-13 14:33:56.661 ERROR 4744 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-9] Exception processing template "mods/editPages/editModPage": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (mods/editPages/editModPage:57)
```

Where line 57 is the line with code:

```
Title: <input type="text" th:field='${formClass.modsLangsTextsRelationses.toArray()[0].getModsLangsTexts().title}' />
```

In the same time, code

```
<p th:text="${formClass.modsLangsTextsRelationses.toArray()[0].getModsLangsTexts().title}" />
```

works fine.

How can I access inner objects from HTML form code with Spring+Hibernate+Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [thymeleaf tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form) :

The `th:field` is a field reference to a command object you declare on the `form` tag thanks to the `th:object` attribute

From the tutorial :

> ```
> <form action="#" th:action="@{/seedstartermng}" th:object="${seedStarter}" method="post">
>     <input type="text" th:field="*{datePlanted}" />
> </form>
> ```

Adapted to your case it would be something like :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{???}" th:object="${formClass.modsLangsTextsRelationses.toArray()[0].getModsLangsTexts()}" method="post">
     <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" />
</form>
```

I have a doubt it will work this way. Have a look at [section 7.6 : dynamic fields](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields)